# Is there a programmatic way to export Postman Collections?

Tags: postman

I have an ever-growing collection of Postman tests for my API that I regularly export and check in to source control, so I can run them as part of CI via Newman.

I'd like to automate the process of exporting the collection when I've added some new tests - perhaps even pull it regularly from Postman's servers and check the updated version in to git.

Is there an API I can use to do this?

I would settle happily for a script I could run to export my collections and environments to named json files.

Answer (score 1):

Such a feature must be available in Postman Pro, when you use the Cloud instance feature(I haven't used it yet, but I'll probably do for continuous integration), I'm also interested and I went through this information:

> FYI, that you don't even need to export the collection. You can use Newman to talk to the Postman cloud instance and call collections directly from there. Therefore, when a collection is updated in Postman, Newman will automatically run the updated collection on its next run.
>
> You can also add in the environment URLs to automatically have Newman environment swap (we use this to run a healthcheck collection across all our environments [Dev, Test, Stage & Prod])

You should check this feature, postman licences are not particularly expensive, it can be worth it.

hope this helps

Alexandre

Answer (score 1):

You have probably solved your problem by now, but for anyone else coming across this, [Postman has an API](https://docs.api.getpostman.com/?version=latest#647806d5-492a-eded-1df6-6529b5dc685c) that lets you access information about your collections. You could call /collections to get a list of all your collections, then query for the one(s) you want by their id. (If the link doesn't work, google "Postman API".)

Comment: It should be really helpful to add some example code directly in your answer.

Comment: The JSON coming via such APIs isn't importable back to Postman